# Attribute validation only when not NULL or empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, data-annotations

Is there a simplify way to validate an attribute only when it's **not** null or empty?

For example I have a attribute where it should be valid when string contains "google.com" and it's a valid URL.

```
[RegularExpression(@"\b(google.com)\b"), Url]
public string MyAttribute { get; set; }
```

But in that way if it's empty it will throw an error.

I would like to have something more practical and generic where I could add other kind of validations to another attributes.

Does this exist?

Comment: You should also use `Required` attribute. This will first validate if the value is provided or not before triggering other validations. What's the error you are getting?

Comment: I was getting invalid url. I also was trying `Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true), DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)`

Comment: If you are not passing any value to the property, isn't it the invalid url? What do want to happen when `MyAttribute` has value null or empty string? What happened when you tried using Required and RegularExpression both together?

Comment: I just expect that when null or empty it became valid, not having to override each class

Answer (score 0):

This question is old, but I think the best way to handle the situation where you want a validation rule to apply only in certain circumstances (such as when the value isn't null or empty) is to put that logic in its own custom validation class and use that instead; for example

```
public class MyAttributeValid : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(object?.ToString())
            return true;

        // other validation code here, such as regex in your case
    }
}
```

and use it like

```
[MyAttributeValid]
public string MyAttribute { get; set; }
```